# How to sort strings numerically in textfile using java?

Tags: java, sorting, file-io, text-files

I need to sort my strings in a textfile. But everytime I compile the program, the textfile looks like this:

```
10::name::birthday::address::email::fax::mobilenum::homeNum::
11::name::birthday::address::email::fax::mobilenum::homeNum::
1::name::birthday::address::email::fax::mobilenum::homeNum::
2::name::birthday::address::email::fax::mobilenum::homeNum::
```

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Phonebook.txt"));
    LinkedList<String> contacts = new LinkedList<String>();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        contacts.add(line);
    }

    Collections.sort(contacts);

    FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("Phonebook.txt");

    for(String sorted:contacts) {
        fileOut.write(sorted+"\n");
    }

    fileOut.close();
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you execute the code? Do you get wrong results/exceptions?

Comment: I just edited the question, sorry.

Comment: Your list was ordered in alphabetic order `a, aa, ab, b, ba, bb, ...`. If you want to sort it using numeric order you need to get numeric part, parse it to Integer and compare it.

Answer (score 2):

> `10::name::birthday::address::email::fax::mobilenum::homeNum::`

I can see a `Class` `Contact` here. You should better create a `Contact` class.

Now, for every line you have separate `Contact`, assuming the first number i.e .`10`  will be unique for every contact.

Create a method which can simply convert your `String` to `Contact` `Object` and by calling method for every line you will have list of `Contact`s.

To make `Collection.sort(contactList)` work your `Contact` class must implement `Comparable`

***For Example :***

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact contact) { 
        //add null check
        return this.id.compareTo(contact.getId());//Considering Integer type for Id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(contacts,new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1.matches("^\\d+\\:\\:.+") && o2.matches("^\\d+\\:\\:.+")) {
                return Integer.parseInt(o1.split("::")[0]) - Integer.parseInt(o2.split("::")[0]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
});
```

This will sort the `contacts` list numerically instead of alphabetically.

Comment: Why the try catch ? Sounds bad

Comment: @Dici I've added it in case the `String`s don't have the expected format, it can be replaced with a couple of checks for that.

Comment: At least make it `NumberFormatException`... even then the `compare` method should just throw an exception, as the two strings could not be compared.

Comment: This is really really bad exception handling, you should fix it.If the string does not have the expected format... well, that should just fail. If I want to buy a computer in euros whereas only dollars are accepted, the saler is not going to give me the computer for free, he's just going to tell me it is not possible

Comment: I wouldn't parse the number for each compare operation - this is likely to be very slow if the file is anything but trivially small.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think it is very large since the OP performs the sort in-memory but in the general case you're right

Comment: @Dici That's hardly justification of anything. Sorting in memory will be **much** faster than any other option. And storing a million items in memory is not exactly rare these days. Sorting a million items with the code would take an eternity.

Answer (score 1):

You can get integer part of your line and in TreeMap you can use it as key, and entire line as value. TreeMap lets us sort our values based on keys, and since we will use `Integer` we will get numeric order, not alphabetic order like in case of String

Your code can look like:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


    map.put(Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("::"))), line);
    //              |            |                 |
    //              |            |            find index of first ::
    //              |       take part of string from start till first ::
    //      convert String to Integer
}       

for (String line : map.values()){
    System.out.println(line);//or write to file
}
```

Comment: Like this one, lightweight (no new class) and efficient